# call meteor core packages method from client

Tags: meteor

I am new to meteor and I could not understand that how methods are imported in Meteor. The methods that are starting with
    Meteor.methodName,
how to call these methods from client if they are exposed in server.

I have a method called Meteor.loginWithpassword in meteor package livechat / livechat.js.
Its package.js file looks like this:

```
Package.onUse(function(api) {
              api.versionsFrom('1.0');
              api.addFiles('livechat.js', 'server');
```

}

Now I want to call Method loginWithPassword method from client.How to achieve this??

Comment: Not sure what you want to do, but `Meteor.loginWithPassword` function from the `accounts-password` package is a client-side function. In your package `livechat.js` is server-side only. Do you want to log in a user on the server side?

Comment: Your question does not make sense, you've nothing to do, as @aedm said loginWithPassword is a client function. Make sure to not use it on the server folder.

Comment: I am trying to call the method from client side only, and that was only my question. I am getting error that loginWithPassword is not a function.

Comment: `loginWithPassword` is accessible only from the server-side. This is why you can't access it from client-side.